# Regex - Parse name with First Last Middle

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to parse names (using *.Net*) that have the following format

> First Last Middle

Here is the trick though, *First* and *Middle* is *optional* so:

if the text is:

> Johnson

Then this is assumed the Last name.

if the text is:
Mary Johnson
Then this is assumed as *First(Mary)* and *Last(Johnson)*

if the text is:

> Mary Johnson Ray Anne

Then this is assumed to be *First(Mary)* and *Last(Johnson)* and *Middle(Ray Anne)*

This is what I have so far:

```
^(?<first>\s*\S+)\s*(?<last>(\S*\s*)*?)(?<middle>\S*\s*)$
```

and here is a link to the partial solution and names:

[RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cfirst%3E%5Cs*%5CS%2B)%5Cs*(%3F%3Clast%3E(%5CS*%5Cs*)*%3F)(%3F%3Cmiddle%3E%5CS*%5Cs*)%24&i=Mary%20Johnson%20Ray%20Anne&o=n)

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?<fn>\S+)\p{Zs}+)?(?<m>\S+\p{Zs}+(?:\S+\p{Zs}+)?)?(?<s>\S+)\p{Zs}*\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a(%3f%3cfn%3e%5cS%2b)%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b)%3f(%3f%3cm%3e%5cS%2b%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b(%3f%3a%5cS%2b%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b)%3f)%3f(%3f%3cs%3e%5cS%2b)%5cp%7bZs%7d*%5cr%3f%24&i=Mary+Johnson+Ray+Anne%0d%0aMary+Johnson%0d%0aJohnson&o=m).But it seems to me you can do it easier without a regex. Split with a space and analyze the parts.

Comment: This is closer, seems like there has to be a way to tell the Last Name to gobble up (greedy) and make the other two lazy based off of this one.  I agree though, for this situation that would be easier, but can't do that this time.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that middle is last. See [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a(%3f%3cfn%3e%5cS%2b)%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b)%3f(%3f%3csn%3e%5cS%2b)%5cp%7bZs%7d*(%3f%3cmn%3e.*%3f)%3f%5cp%7bZs%7d*%5cr%3f%24&i=Mary+Johnson+Ray+Anne%0d%0aMary+Johnson%0d%0aJohnson&o=m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:(?<first>\w+)\s+)?(?<last>\w+)\s*(?<middle>.*)
```

Comment: makes sense but is there any way to do this using the Named Captures?  This is a configurable regex that depends on the named groups.

Comment: @PMil, actually, I got an epiphany. Check out my update.

Comment: @ndn i was about to post almost the same, but making the middle-group optional and taking care of trailing spaces, see https://regex101.com/r/bK6tQ4/1 - if its of any relevance

Comment: @SebastianProske, the middle part is sort of optional (`.*` can match 0 characters).

Comment: Just posting my final regex.  made a slight tweak to allow leading spaces and non Alpha numeric characters:  ^\s*(?:(?<first>\S+)\s+)?(?<last>\S+)\s*(?<middle>.*)

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?<first>\w+)\s)?(?<last>\w+)(\s?(?<middle>\w+))*$
```

This will get them into all the capture groups you want, but middle will have one or more captures (the first being empty if none) depending on how many middle names the person has and will need to be joined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for primitivism,  but why not to

```
        private Tuple<string, string, string> Parse(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return null;

            var arr = input.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (arr.Length == 1)
            {
                return new Tuple<string, string, string>(null, null, arr[0]);
            }

            if (arr.Length == 2)
            {
                return new Tuple<string, string, string>(arr[0], null, arr[1]);
            }

            return new Tuple<string, string, string>(arr[0], String.Join(" ", arr.Skip(1).Take(arr.Length - 2)), arr[arr.Length - 1]);
        }
```